# Fixing permissions after FTPing ASP.NET code to a Linux system

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, ftp, mono

First off, I'm running Mono to run ASP.NET on Linux, but that's not the question.

It appears that, every time I clear out my application directory and upload, I have to go back in and fix the permissions.  What I'm doing is

```
chmod -R -c 755 /var/www/*
```

...and there are two questions.

1. What's the deal with having to do this every time I FTP?  Feels flaky.
2. Is there a better permissions set than 755?  Do I want different permissions for the /bin directory?  Or can I fix this all with one fell swoop of `chown`?

Comment: What default permissions are the files created with?  Does the ftp account you are logging in with have umask set?

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on your FTP server and configuration. I always used this and it worked:

```
chmod 777 /path/...
```